# Adding a service reference to a WCF service that is using Net.TCP

Tags: wcf, tcp

I am new to creating WCF services. I have created a WCF service that is using TCP. The service is running on IIS 7. From within the solution file I have a client project that I have used to test my service. I've run the client project using a TCP endpoint and it accesses the service and everything is fine.

Now, I want to access my TCP service from a new standalone project, one that is not part of the service's solution like the client project. I created a new project in VS 2008. I clicked on Add Service Reference, entered the net.tcp address (net.tcp//.......) and clicked go. An error is returned saying that the "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved."

Is there something further in IIS 7 that needs to be configured? Am I correctly adding a reference to a service that is using TCP? If needed I can supply more information but at this point I am not too sure what I need to post. As I said the service works perfectly from the client project but I can't even access the service from a standalone project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show us the server side config?? Do you have a MEX endpoint on net.tcp configured??

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Web.config file. Do you have an entry that starts out like
`<endpoint address="mex"`...
and then specifies a contract="IMetadataExhange?  If not then you need to add a meta data exchange endpoint.

If you have $29 to spare, you can save yourself a LOT of time and watch some great [videos by Aaron Skonnard](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=wcf-by-example) on WCF (in the beginner examples there is an 8 minute video on hosting WCF in IIS), The $29 gets you a one month subscription so you can watch anything in the library. Money very well spent in my opinion. [Edit] I forgot to mention you can get a free trial, I think it's good for a month or 4 hours of viewing whichever comes first.